# Automatically carousel rotation for image blocks

Tags: javascript, carousel

I need to change pics in carousel automatically every 2 sec. Cause i'm not good at JS at all could you help me, where i need to add a timer ?
Here html part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
</script>
```

and links for all js files:
http://pastebin.com/AgBGXY4M
http://pastebin.com/4HziWhTw

Answer (score 0):

you have two options to achieve this:

1) Edit js file at line `itemSpeed = 500` to `itemSpeed = 2000` (2000 milliseconds = 2 sec)

2) Pass itemSpeed as an option while calling

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ca-container').contentcarousel({
    itemSpeed : 2000
});
</script>
```

use whatever works for your best.

Comment: i need to switch it automaticaly every 2 sec. without clicking arrows